# Can SNI be enabled without problems to servers that do not support SNI in TLS handshake

Tags: php, ssl, sni

We want to enable SNI (Server Name Indication) in a PHP client that connects to various external endpoints (SOAP/REST). Some of these endpoints support SNI as a server, but some don't. Can enabling SNI on all outgoing request cause problems on servers that do not support SNI?

Comment: I imagine the answer would be yes, because the server would not be able to identify which account it should present you with.

Comment: I would expect that you would get a TLS error that the certificate is invalid because the server would produce the default (or first domain) certificate which would not nessecarily be the certificate required for the specific domain requested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In our case we would enable SNI on all outgoing connections, thus always send the correct virtual domain to the server. But the question is, how will a server respond when it doesn't know about SNI, and does not have multiple certificates installed on 1 IP-address, but just one.

Comment: See my second comment. That's what I would expect to happen in such situations.

Comment: In this case we could set the CNmatch to the domain that is used in the certificate and we would have a working connection. But what happens if we connect with SNI enabled to test.example.org and the server test.example.org has a valid certificate for test.example.org but has not implemented SNI. Would the server not accept the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SNI is an optional  TLS extension ("server_name"). This means any proper TLS stack which does not explicitly support this extension will ignore it. SNI is widely used and all modern browsers have enabled it.

This gives some confidence that almost all sites should work if you use TLS with SNI enabled. There might be still some sites out there which use a broken TLS stack which will fail just because SNI is present. But these sites will fail too when accessed by a modern browser.  Also, way more sites will fail if SNI is not present, like everything behind Cloudflare Free SSL. Thus enabling SNI by default and maybe dealing with the fallout of a very few broken sites is definitely better then dealing with lots of sites which don't work without SNI.

Comment: Thanks! In our case it's more about webservices (not accessed through a browser) than websites accessed through a browser, but i think the same approach applies. Only problem is that our service needs to ensure that all connections are working, even if a server does not have a proper TLS implementation. I guess we just have to test all endpoints with SNI enabled. The chance of a bad TLS implementation is very low I would reckon, right?

Comment: @jaronaz: Chance of bad TLS depends on the kind of services you access. Typically you'll find bad TLS implementations on really old and on small embedded systems. But with bad or old TLS you usually have also different problems at the TLS level before you get to SNI, like no support for current TLS protocol versions or secure ciphers.

Comment: Thanks that helped me. I think most if not all endpoints we use support TLS1.0 or higher, so I think it is safe to say that enabling SNI would not cause any problems, though we should test to be sure ;)